# Correlation matrix shows $0.6$ between independent variable $x_1$ and $x_2$, keep or drop?

Tags: statistics, covariance, correlation, mean-square-error

**Given Correlation Matrix**
[image]

There seems to be some correlation between two of my independent variables *Bedrooms* and *Bed*.

> This is what the metrics shows before and after I drop one of the variable
>
> - **Before dropping Bed**
>   $R^2: 0.73$ and $MSE: 683.058140$
> - **After dropping Bed**
>   $R^2: 0.70$ and $MSE: 754.998619$

It seems like keeping [both of the variables](https://vitalflux.com/mean-square-error-r-squared-which-one-to-use/) give a better. Does that mean I should ignore that the correlation is high between the two variables?

Comment: Without further information on your data it will be difficult to answer your question. How many variables do you have? How many observations? What is your correlation matrix? Have you tried to test multicollinearity?

Comment: @MachineLearner I updated the post with a picture and changed the text. Could you elaborate what you mean with test multicollinearity, do you mean calculating VIF?